# Insert editable graph created in R in an existing excel file

Tags: r, excel, dml

I would like to add an editable graph created in R, which is a `dml` object, into a excel workbook with sheets containing already tables with data. Actually, I have to create a new Excel workbook by the function `read_xlsx()`. I can insert a non editable graph, but it is not the goal.

Comment: It does not seem as though there is a package for that yet. You can definitely embed r plots as images. But unless you create a package of your own or write a script, there is no easy way to create Excel native charts in r...that I know of....